# Use return value of a function as a string in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, typescript1.8

This is the markup I want to place the returned value:

```html
<h2>{{getSelectedUserName}}</h2>
```

This is the function I want to use, which returns a string:

```typescript
public getSelectedUserName(): string {
    let firstName = this.selectedUser.name.split("\\s+")[0];

    console.log(this.selectedUser.name.split("\\s+"));
    console.log(firstName);
    return firstName;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're not calling the function. You need

```
{{ getSelectedUserName() }}
```